# Why am I getting encoding problems with phpspreadsheet?

Tags: php, character-encoding, phpspreadsheet

I'm trying to get a [phpspreadsheet](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet) hello world code working... Just copied from their examples (that work properly) to a new php. But by navigating it, a corrupted xls files gets created. I think it has something to do with encoding, but my document is pure utf-8 (sublime text), and the code is copied from their working example:

```
 <?php
  require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

  use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Helper\Sample;
  use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory;
  use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;

  require_once 'vendor/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/src/Bootstrap.php';

  $helper = new Sample();
  if ($helper->isCli()) {
      $helper->log('This example should only be run from a Web Browser' . PHP_EOL);

      return;
  }

  // Create new Spreadsheet object
  $spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();

  // Set document properties
  $spreadsheet->getProperties()->setCreator('Maarten Balliauw')
      ->setLastModifiedBy('Maarten Balliauw')
      ->setTitle('Office 2007 XLSX Test Document')
      ->setSubject('Office 2007 XLSX Test Document')
      ->setDescription('Test document for Office 2007 XLSX, generated using PHP classes.')
      ->setKeywords('office 2007 openxml php')
      ->setCategory('Test result file');

  // Add some data
  $spreadsheet->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
      ->setCellValue('A1', 'Hello')
      ->setCellValue('B2', 'world!')
      ->setCellValue('C1', 'Hello')
      ->setCellValue('D2', 'world!');

  // Miscellaneous glyphs, UTF-8
  $spreadsheet->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
      ->setCellValue('A4', 'Miscellaneous glyphs')
      ->setCellValue('A5', 'éàèùâêîôûëïüÿäöüç');

  // Rename worksheet
  $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Simple');

  // Set active sheet index to the first sheet, so Excel opens this as the first sheet
  $spreadsheet->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

  // Redirect output to a client’s web browser (Xls)
  header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="01simple.xls"');
  header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
  // If you're serving to IE 9, then the following may be needed
  header('Cache-Control: max-age=1');

  // If you're serving to IE over SSL, then the following may be needed
  header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'); // Date in the past
  header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s') . ' GMT'); // always modified
  header('Cache-Control: cache, must-revalidate'); // HTTP/1.1
  header('Pragma: public'); // HTTP/1.0

  $writer = IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Xls');
  $writer->save('php://output');
  exit;
```

What I get is this:

[image]

So what? Why?

Comment: You need to make sure that everything is set/saved as UTF-8. Preferably without BOM (byte order mark).

Comment: thank you, how to do it?

Comment: Use a code editor and open the file(s) and check to see if they are indeed UTF-8. The encoding menu will show you right away which type it/they are saved as.

Comment: ...and the very strange thing is, that their examples, served from the same server, same subdir, and same code, just work! I previously use some code of mine too, but same results..

Comment: As I wrote, the original document is pure utf-8, made with sublime text.

Comment: Hard to say. If you're using this on a hosted site, make sure that it's not modifying its encoding on the way. Some have a default encoding for certain files (extensions). Even if one file isn't set right that works in conjunction with what you're using for all this, will affect its output. Try and check if something isn't set as UTF-8 somewhere. There isn't much else I can say, sorry.

Comment: I'm in local environment, pure MAMP PRO. Same identical file, served properly from their examples dir, wrong from a couple of outer dirs (same site)

Comment: OFF didn't you have issues with the memory needs and the performance of the spreadsheet generator before? I might remember that we had issues with both of them and then I switched to this: https://github.com/mk-j/PHP_XLSXWriter /OFF

Comment: also; it looks good in the LibreOffice to me. Did you know that XLS files are zipped XML files?

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem with Lithuanian characters. The solution is to open the php file with code as example in EmEditor. In the right bottom corner check the encoding (usually if I create a new php file and add into this file strings with Lithuanian characters the encoding by default will be Baltic)  and if it is not UTF-8 without Signature save this file with Encoding: UTF-8 without Signature (this selection will appear in the bottom right corner when the Save As function will be executed).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe these lines can work for you, put them at the beginning of the file.

```
ini_set('default_charset', '');
mb_http_output('pass');
mb_detect_order(["UTF-8"]);
```